# LoadRunner SSL Certificate issue

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, loadrunner

I am trying to monitor a https URL using VirtualUser Generator, I have the pfx certificate of the user which is used to login as a user on the portal. I used the Openssl utility with Loadrunner to convert the same to PEM and used web_set_certificate_ex on my script but still I see the script demands user certificate for the user. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to monitor

I don't know exactly what you mean by trying to "monitor" the URL using vugen but the latter part of your question sounds like you're trying to record a script and play it back.  Since this is generally the function of vugen I'll answer this question.  I'm also going to assume you're recording in the web/http protocol and not something like truClient.

Here's the thing - vugen will generally take care of the certificate exchange for you.  The primary exception to this is mobile testing.  I also actually made the same mistake I think you're making when I first started perf testing.  I spent quite a bit of time futzing with certificates, but that is generally unnecessary.

You should make an attempt to record a very simple script, like login, and play it back.  If it works, you're set.  If you happen to be testing a middleware application you should consider recording in clear text and adding an 's' to your http:// URI.

Very simple advice, but if I understand the nature of your inquiry, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording without certificate and see weather you can see the request bodies, if not, then you can think of placing client certificates also make sure you are using the right socket, SSL version and cipers to record the application.